# If I remove a file from a branch and make a PR to a destination branch that has that file, will it remove the file from the destination branch too?

Tags: git

I have a branch where file.txt was accidentally modified earlier in the commit graph.  That branch also has other changes in different commits.  There's a main branch that includes file.txt.  I want to make a PR to the main branch that shows all changes besides the change to file.txt.

I removed the file with `git rm --cached file.txt` and committed.  But if these changes get merged to the main branch, on the main branch will file.txt remain and continue to be tracked there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. It will be removed from the main branch.

One simple solution to this is that you can copy the content of your remote branch and put it in your current branch's file.txt.

When you raise the merge request, you should not see any difference in this file.